# How to create code lens action next to code line in vs code, something similar to GitLens

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions, gitlens

[image]
In git lens I can see the commit details gets added to the right of the code line. Does anyone knows which feature of VS code extension us used to display such message in the right side of the code line. When I searched, I could see that Code lens extensions only support the action displayed on top of the line. Then which feature helps git lens to display the action on the right side of code.

Comment: is it a line decoration